# How to generate and store correlative numbers in django

Tags: python, django, ldap

I'm working with ldapdb for django. When adding I must generate an uid number for the new entry. For that, I want to know how to store a correlative number in my database (or somewhere else) since django manages my database automatically. Thus, I have a correlative in 300, the new uid would be 301 and I would do something like employee.uid = 301.

```
@login_required
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            employee = form.save(commit=False)
            '''for property, value in vars(employee).iteritems():
                print property, ": ", value'''
            employee.dn = ''

            employee.photo = None
            employee.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/employees/')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Damn!!!')
    else:
        form = EmployeeForm()
    return render(request, 'employees/detail.htm', {'form':form, 'action': 'add'})
```

Answer (score 0):

uid doesn't serial number feel free to use md5 hash or something else. But if you want get next serial number just get all objects at the table and pass this list to len function, I dont know django ORM good but I think this is a must like

```
len(models.employes.all()) + 1
```